# Async Task inside BroadcastReceiver onReceive method not running?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcastreceiver

I have a working app which sends String data from application's input textfield to TCP server on my PC. 
I have added BroadcastReceiver class to send message to computer when it's received.
Application receives messages(Toast is working), but I can't make it send received message to PC.

No Errors. Application just skips methods called.

How Do I Call a method inside onReceive?

Thank You for any help!

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
String phone;
String message;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle intentExtras = intent.getExtras();

    if (intentExtras != null) {
        // Get Messages
        Object[] sms = (Object[]) intentExtras.get("pdus");

        for (int i = 0; i < sms.length; ++i) {
            // Parse Each Message
            SmsMessage smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) sms[i]);

            phone = smsMessage.getOriginatingAddress();
            message = smsMessage.getMessageBody().toString();
            System.out.println("Message is: "+message);
            Log.i("sth","message "+message);

            //What i have tried
            sendMessage(message);

            //creating instance
            MessageSender messageSender = new MessageSender();
            messageSender.execute(message);

            //calling metod from MainActivity
            ((MainActivity)context.getApplicationContext()).send2(message);

            MainActivity.send2(message);

            //toast is working fine
            Toast.makeText(context,"Alert:"+ phone + ": " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
public void sendMessage(String s)
{
    MessageSender messageSender = new MessageSender();
    messageSender.execute(s);
}
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText e1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    e1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    //This works
    MessageSender messageSender = new MessageSender();
    messageSender.execute("App launched!");
}

//On Button click. Working good.
public void send(View v)
{
    MessageSender messageSender = new MessageSender();
    messageSender.execute(e1.getText().toString());
}
//For test purposes
public static void send2(String s)
{
    MessageSender messageSender = new MessageSender();
    messageSender.execute(s);
}
```

MessageSender

```
public class MessageSender extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>
{
Socket s;
DataOutputStream dos;
PrintWriter pw;

@Override
public Void doInBackground(String... voids) {

    String message = voids[0];
try {
    s = new Socket("192.168.1.69", 7800);
    pw = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
    pw.write(message);
    pw.flush();
    pw.close();
    s.close();

}catch(IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
    return null;
}
```

}

Added server code:

```
  public class MyServerFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame 
  {
  static Socket s;
   static ServerSocket ss;
  static InputStreamReader isr;
  static BufferedReader br;
  static String message;public MyServerFrame() 
 {

}

public static void main(String args[]) 
{   
    try 
    {
        ss = new ServerSocket(7800);
        while(true)
        {
            s=ss.accept();
            isr = new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream());
            br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            StringBuilder everything = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while( (line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
            {
               everything.append(line);
            }
            message = everything.toString();//multiple to onelinestring 
            System.out.println(message);
        }   
    }catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Why do you think the application is skipping the method? And can you post your server code thats on the pc also?

Comment: Thank You for your reply! Added server code. I don't get any errors on receiving message, however i don't get message to server. On the other hand, Toast is working, so message String is not null.

Comment: I would appreciate any thoughts, or possible solutions.

Comment: I would advise you to use a while loop when reading from the buffered reader while its not null to ensure that it is printing all the data that comes from the socket and not just the first line

Comment: Yes it wasn't reading all lines in multiple line strings. Updated server code above. Now it does (tested on getting text from multiple line textfield on button click). However it didnt solve the issue. Still nothing happens on sms message receive. I just get a Toast.

Comment: Is their a firewall on the computer, can you try pinging the computer from the the android device?

Comment: No Firewall. Pinging (a real device) succesful (no packet loss, reasonable ping~10ms). I am testing this application on both: AVD and  real smartphone connected to wifi on same network as PC. Getting same results. Thank you for trying. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Im just trying to get the situation clear, when you click the button it works fine, but the on click receiver is only showing the toast but not sending the message, is this correct?

Comment: I figured it out, since broadcast receivers are meant for short code that runs quickly, your program gets killed before the AsyncTask executes. The way to solve this would be to start a service that makes the network request in your onREceive method

Comment: Yes, I can send typed text from text field or any other string when calling method with button click. When android receives sms message onReceive shows the toast but does not send message to PC.

Comment: I will try your proposal and let you know when i solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that since you are executing the Network Request using an Async Task in the onReceive method, the onReceive method returns before the AsyncTask executes since an Async Task is Asynchronous. Therefore the process that is running the onRequest method becomes a low priority since the onReceive method has returned and the operating system will kill it before your Async Task actually executes.

Here are two solutions:

First ensure that the receiver is declared in your Android manifest, then do one of the following.

1. Instead of calling an Async Task to execute your network request, create a service and use the service to run the network code.
2. You can call the `goAsync()` method in the onReceive method to tell the system to give the receiver more time to execute its Async Task. The code for this would be something like this:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
   //create a pending intend that you will pass to the Async task so you can tell the system when the Async Task finished so that it can recycle.
   final PendingResult pendingResult = goAsync();
    AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> asyncTask = new AsyncTask<String,  Integer, String>() {
       @Override
       protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
           //put the network calling code in here

           // Must call finish() so the BroadcastReceiver can be recycled.
           pendingResult.finish();
           return data;
       }
   };
   asyncTask.execute();
    }
   ```

The second way I believe would be simpler, so I would reccomend using that as it doesnt require you to create a whole new service.

Comment: First of all I want to apologize for wasting your time. Your second solution works as are simple method calls in my question. The Reason was - Receiver wasn't declared in Manifest file. I didn't even think to check it as Toast from receiver was working in AVD(dont know why). Now all works fine.

Comment: Thank you for your effort and sorry for my lack of android programming experience.

Comment: if we implement onPostExecute method then where will be the place for         pendingResult.finish(); ?

Comment: I am getting this error "Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: Broadcast already finished
       at android.content.BroadcastReceiver$PendingResult.sendFinished(BroadcastReceiver.java:248)
       at android.content.BroadcastReceiver$PendingResult.finish(BroadcastReceiver.java:233)"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks SteelToe for leading me to this trivial solution:

> Receiver was not declared in manifest file.